# NGINX - Dynamic throttling of bandwidth

Tags: nginx, rate-limiting, throttling

I am going to deploy a website with several big media files (~10 GiB) and I would like to balance the load on it.

NGINX will be used to serve the files. What I would like to achieve is something that has already been discussed here, but no real answer has been received.

These two posts have similar intentions:

[Dynamic throttling of bandwidth](https://serverfault.com/questions/507596/dynamic-throttling-of-bandwidth)

[Balancing server bandwith](https://serverfault.com/questions/556924/balancing-server-bandwith?rq=1)

I have a Gigabit pipe and I would like to give each user an equal quantity of bandwidth. (ie. one user downloading would have the whole Gig, two users would have 500Mbps/ea, and so on)

Is there any way to achieve this kind of "dynamic throttling" with nginx? I am aware that there is a way to throttle users' bandwidth with Nginx, but poses the following problem:

The normal throttling would just allocate eg. 100Mbps per user, but if there is just a single user downloading the rest of the pipe would be underutilized.

Comment: You didn't ask where anything.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make it clear, I just wanted to know if there is some way of dynamically throttle bandwidth with NGINX, an example is posted on the penultimate paragraph (1 user > 1Gbit for him/her; 2 users > 500Mbps/each; 3 users > 333Mbps/each and so on.)